# Netplan - Multiple Nic config

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I have a netplan config as follows on fresh install of 18.04:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens224:
      addresses: [192.168.10.10/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.10.1]
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.10.0/24
          via: 192.168.10.1
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.10.1
    ens192:
      addresses: [192.168.30.10/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.30.1]
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.30.0/24
          via: 192.168.30.1
```

I have 2 distinct networks (192.168.10.0/24 (Management) & 192.168.30.0/24 (User)) and they are connected via a router.

With the above Netplan, the server only responds to pings from the local subnet. e.g. from my pc on the user network, I can ping 192.168.30.10 OK but not 192.168.10.10, I get Request timed out. On the server I can see the following TCPDUMP output.

18:30:37.929682 ARP, Request who-has _gateway (Broadcast) tell 192.168.10.200, length 46
18:30:37.930562 ARP, Request who-has _gateway (Broadcast) tell 192.168.10.200, length 46
18:30:41.982129 IP xxxxx.example.com > ubuntu: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 405, length 40
18:30:46.598802 IP xxxxx.example.com > ubuntu: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 406, length 40
18:30:51.601718 IP xxxxx.example.com > ubuntu: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 407, length 40
18:30:56.598075 IP xxxxx.example.com > ubuntu: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 408, length 40
18:31:05.525346 ARP, Request who-has _gateway (Broadcast) tell 192.168.10.204, length 46
18:31:05.525556 ARP, Request who-has _gateway (Broadcast) tell 192.168.10.204, length 46

What do I need to change in my netplan to enable it to respond to requests from any subnet on any NIC?
eg.

- SSH from User network or management network to management IP
- Ping from any network to any NIC

Comment: The easy fix is to enable reverse path filtering in loose mode with `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2`. However, that's frowned upon by some folks. I have a similar question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169002/how-to-use-netplan-to-create-two-seperate-routing-tables